# airportd keeps crashing

Tags: wifi, airport, crash

I'm running a Macbook Pro retina 13 inches early 2015 with 16 Go of RAM and a 3,1 GHz intel core i7 on OS X El Captain 10.11.1

I keep having some problems with airportd that crashes really often. Sometimes, when I click on the wifi icon on the menu bar, I have the rainbow crash cursor showing up and the menu is not popping up. Then, my mac starts heating up a lot and slowing down and I can hear a loud fan noise. When I check on the activity monitor, the airportd process is taking a huge amount a RAM and 100 % of the processor (sometimes more !). Actually, blued is also taking almost 50 % of the processor...
I have to kill it manually with the activity monitor for it to get back to normal. But the problem is that happens every 20 minutes in average.
I don't know what to do, this is really annoying, I beg for your help !

I keep having this in my system.log :

```
Dec 13 15:30:21 3wxmr8aqljon9umcd airportd[79737]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
```

I have that after I kill airportd after a crash:

```
13/12/2015 16:28:20,755 airportd[79737]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
13/12/2015 16:29:35,668 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.airportd[79737]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
13/12/2015 16:29:35,777 airportd[3201]: _ipv6Request: Unable to attach IPv6 on awdl0 (File exists)
13/12/2015 16:29:35,865 airportd[3201]: airportdProcessDLILEvent: en0 attached (up)
13/12/2015 16:29:36,141 airportd[3201]: _ipv6Request: Unable to attach IPv6 on awdl0 (File exists)
13/12/2015 16:29:37,229 airportd[3201]: _createP2PDeviceInterface: Failed to create P2P device interface for en0 (Operation already in progress)
13/12/2015 16:29:38,877 locationd[91]: wifi scan failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.airportd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.airportd}
13/12/2015 16:29:46,759 airportd[3201]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
13/12/2015 16:29:46,761 airportd[3201]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
13/12/2015 16:29:46,761 airportd[3201]: WARNING: AvStats (526) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.scan, temporarily allowing request with background priority —— all entitlement requirements will be strictly enforced in a future release
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the update to 10.11.2 first and see if that helps.

Comment: Well, it have been happening before upgrading to OSX 10.11.1 but I'll try to update to 10.11.2, thanks.

Comment: Oky, the update is done. It's kindda better, but I still get some crashes when there is a heavy charge on the network usage...